# 200 stream not found issue with Amazon s3 authenticated URL

Tags: amazon-s3, flowplayer, jwplayer6

Been using stackoverflow for ages, finally I have got a question and cant find answer anywhere. I am using Amazon S3's authenticated URL for video streaming and have an issue that I cannot root cause. The issue is I get `200, stream not found error`, only on some browsers.

Note:
1) I have tried `flowplayer` and `jwplayer` and have same/similar issues.
2) I am using latest releases of the browser as of today.
3) Problem only with Authenticated URL.
4) The systems being tested are all in the same time zone and their ISP's are in the same timezone too. So it is definitely not an issue with timezone.

Case 1 : Windows 7 Laptop, streams fine on IE and firefox, Get stream not found error in Chrome. 
Case 2 : different Windows 7 Laptop, streams fine on all the browsers.
Case 3 : another different Windows 7 Laptop, does not stream on any browsers.

Any pointers to where to look for will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but maybe it can helps somebody else.
On amazon S3, when you upload a video file, by default the encoding is not the good one. Some browsers can be disturbed by this.
Check on video properties the Content-type is set too video/mp4 for mp4 videos and video/webm for webm videos etc...